# Boost.Hana: Transform tuple of values to tuple of corresponding types in constexpr context

Tags: c++, types, tuples, constexpr, boost-hana

Recently I had to write a transformation from a tuple of values to the (constexpr) tuple of the types of the values.

```cpp
namespace hana = boost::hana;

// we have this (not neccessarily constexpr)
auto value_tuple = hana::make_tuple(1, 'a');

// we want this (must be constexpr)
constexpr auto type_tuple = hana::make_tuple(hana::type_c<int>, hana::type_c<char>);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with uses `hana::transform` and `hana::typeid_` in an unevaluated context to allow for the result to be constexpr.
It relies on `hana::type` being default-constructible (as documented in `hana::type_c`) and `hana::tuple` being default-constructible if all of the element types are.

```cpp
constexpr auto to_types = [](auto values) {
  namespace hana = boost::hana;
  return decltype(hana::transform(
      hana::to_tuple(std::declval<decltype(values)>()), hana::typeid_)){};
};
```

If you know that `values` can be used with `hana::transform` directly then `hana::to_tuple` can be dropped (eg. `std::array` cannot be transformed directly).

This can be used to implement finding the common element type of a `hana::tuple`:

```cpp
constexpr auto to_common_type = [](auto types) {
  namespace hana = boost::hana;
  return hana::unpack(types, hana::template_<std::common_type_t>);
};

using value_type =
    typename decltype(to_common_type(to_types(values)))::type;
```

Comment: FWIW there is also a `hana::experimental::types` template that is a list of types instead of using a tuple.